# Верстка блока с картинками

Tags: css, вёрстка

Всем здравствуйте! Не так давно начала осваивать верстку и пока испытываю проблемы с подбором инструментов к задаче.

Сейчас задача собрать большой блок из картинок в ряды, под каждой размещается короткая подпись (фамилия, имя). Не могу понять,как лучше это сделать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовала flex, но не понравилось, как ведут себя блоки при ресайзе, плюс появились не ясные мне расстояния между блоками.

```
.box_gorozhane {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
 justify-content: space-around;
 }
.img_gorozhane {
position: relative;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center;
}
```

Также попробовала display: inline-block, но в таком случае съезжает подпись к фото.

Каким образом лучше всего это реализовать?

HTML код сейчас такой

```
<div class=box_gorozhane>
<div class=img_gorozhane>
<img src=".png">
<p>Фамилия Имя</p>
</div>
<div class=img_gorozhane>
<img src=".png">
<p>Фамилия Имя</p>
</div>
<div class=img_gorozhane>
<img src=".png">
<p>Фамилия Имя</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1 - inline-block:**

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

.bit {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  margin: .25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div><div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div><div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div><div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div><div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div><div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div><div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div><div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2 - flex ([поддержка](http://*%7Bbox-sizing:%20border-box;%7D%20%20.row%20%7B%20%20%20overflow:%20hidden;%20%7D%20%20a%20%7B%20%20%20display:%20block;%20%7D%20%20.bit%20%7B%20%20%20text-align:%20center;%20%20%20padding:%20.5%25;%20%20%20%7D%20%20@media%20(min-width:%20500px)%7B%20%20%20.bit%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20text-align:%20center;%20%20%20%20%20width:%2020%25;%20%20%20%20%20float:%20left;%20%20%20%20%20padding:%20.5%25;%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%7D)):**

```css
.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

.bit {
  text-align: center;
  margin: .25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант с float:**

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

.bit {
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5%;  
}

@media (min-width: 500px){
  .bit {
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: .5%;  
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
  <div class="bit">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ccc/fff" alt="">
    <a href="#">Name Name</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень хорошие варианты, возьму себе их все на заметку! В своей задаче использовала вариант с float

Answer (score 0):

Я бы все-таки делал с flex, но можно и с инлайнблоками, если вы хотите "контролировать" все расстояния и размеры. Например так:

```css
.img_gorozhane{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  margin:10px;
  background:lightgrey;
}

.img_gorozhane p {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  left:10px;
  margin:0;
}

.img_gorozhane img {
 background:grey;
 width:190px;
 height:260px;
 position:relative;
 top:5px;
 left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class=box_gorozhane>
<div class=img_gorozhane>
<img src=".png">
<p>Фамилия Имя</p>
</div>
<div class=img_gorozhane>
<img src=".png">
<p>Фамилия Имя</p>
</div>
<div class=img_gorozhane>
<img src=".png">
<p>Фамилия Имя</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: флекс мне тоже симпатичнее, но у меня почему-то появляются непонятные отступы внутри флекс-бокса (хотя все изображения одинаковые по размеру) и странно ползут при ресайзе. Хотя с инлайн и вовсе никак не ползут)

Comment: У вас стоит свойство  `justify-content: space-around;` для контейнера, оно распределяет контент в контейнере равномерно с отступами между контентам и стенками. Замените его на `justify-content: flex-start;` и весь контент прижмется к левой стенке контейнера.

Comment: все-равно какие-то фото почему-то начинают растягиваться. Что необходимо прописать в таблице стилей, чтобы они сохраняли свои пропорции?

Comment: вам необходимо задать стили для `.img_gorozhane{flex: 0 0 200px}`, также размеры и` background-size:cover;` для img. (200 пикселей написал для примера)